# How to make the receiver send signal back to the transmitter with wireless RF 433MHz module

Tags: arduino, rf, rfid, transmitter, receiver

I want to buy a RF transmitter & receiver 433MHz on the internet for our research project which deals with radio frequency.

I badly need the concept of having the receiver notify the transmitter or giving the transmitter a signal so that the controller/owner of the device would be notified if the receiver is still receiving a signal or if it is out of range.

I'm wondering because all I know is that it only works with a transmitter sending signal to the receiver and decoding the signal.

I want to copy the idea from an alarm system for motorcycle when the alarm is triggered, the remote control also vibrates and lights on to notify the owner when his/her vehicle is being moved or stolen.

Comment: The fixed function 433 MHz radio modules are horrible to begin with, you should replace them with a digital packet radio for either 433 MHz (Si446x, CC1101, etc) or if 2.4 GHz works the NRF24 and compatibles are far cheaper.  All of these are transceivers so you can implement bi-directional communication.  But this seems to be an off-topic part shopping question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *transmitter* is something that *sends* a signal. A *receiver* is something that *gets* a signal.

A transmitter never receives and a receiver never transmits.

If you have a device that does both, either alternating between transmitting and receiving (half-duplex) or by using a duplexer (full-duplex) it is normally called a transceiver or in some cases an rf-modem (modulator/demodulator) or a XXX radio (where XXX is the name of the particular radio standard it uses, such as WiFi or Zigbee). In all of those cases it includes at least one transmitter AND one receiver on both ends.

The motorcycle remote that you are describing is a transceiver.

Answer (score 2):

Communication is one way only transmitter to receiver.

You could get a second transmitter and receiver.

Comment: May I ask how does motorcycle alarm system works? and what module do they use in order for the remote control to receive signals from the vehicle?

Comment: could be NRF24L01, Zigbee, Z-wave, etc.